# "Функция - объект первого класса" - почему?

Tags: javascript, терминология

В различной литературе (в частности на википедии, у Стефанова, у Сошникова) функции в *JavaScript* называют "объектами первого класса". Понятно, что функция - объект. Но почему именно "первого класса" и что это вообще значит - нигде не разъясняется. Поэтому, прошу объяснить. Возможно, есть какие-то критерии, по которым *нечто* можно определить как объект первого класса?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно почитать [это](http://wiki.c2.com//?FirstClass) или ["Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs "](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#call_footnote_Temp_121) (за авторством Gerald Jay Sussman и Harry Abelson).

Если критерии функции первого класса сформулировать, то:

- С ними можно работать как с переменными.
- Могут быть переданы как аргумент в процедуру.
- Могут быть возвращены как результат выполнения процедуры.
- Могут быть включены в другие структуры данных.

Если в двух словах, то, в JavaScript это означает, что всё, что вы можете делать с Integer, String, Array или любыми другими объектами, вы можете также делать и с функциями.